# Easy to implement calendar

Tags: html, calendar

I want to place a nice-looking calendar on a webpage. What's the easiest one to implement? I've tried jQuery datepicker, but I have to include all the ui-s, download some files, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll save **lots** of time and effort by sticking with the jQuery solution.

If you go to the [download page](http://jqueryui.com/download), you'll see that you can customize your package to include *only* the datepicker component and *only* the theme(s) you want.

Comment: I include the .js's but I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'datepicker'"

Comment: Oh, I found the "bug", I was including jquery 1.4.1 instead of 1.4.4 :D

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery datepicker is pretty darn easy. You include two `.js` files and a stylesheet, then run `$('#calendar').datepicker()`. If you want to use someone else's work, it's not that much to ask to *download* it.

In fact, you don't even have to. Google hosts the [Javascript](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI) and [CSS](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2009/03/jquery-ui-17/) files, so you don't even have to download. Go forth and implement.

Comment: I tried this, but when I include the CSS file the jQuery won't work on the page ...

Comment: @Cristy: in what way does it fail to work? Are there errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: No, there are no erros, but the javascript is not working ;\ (not only the datepicker, but also other javascript scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Google actually has an API. You can use it :)

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/